# Android/Java: using a string for a variable

Tags: android

I am trying to read in values from a string array in an xml file that contains many arrays.  Currently I am using this to import the array.

```
String[] NEWARRAYNAME = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ARRAYNAME);
```

what I would like to do is use a random number to get a random array from my file.  I was thinking of naming all my arrays in the xml document : m1, m2, m3 ect since I couldn't just use a number(I'm trying to emulate a DB tag).  This is what I am doing at the moment to generate a string that incorporates the random number.

```
int i = random.nextInt(3)+ 1;
String ID = "m" + Integer.toString(i);
```

So how can I use the string ID to get the array from my xml file.
using GetResources().getStringArray(R.array.ID) doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getIdentifier](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to get the identifier for the name you'd otherwise get from R. Note that it's much slower than using the identifier straight from R. You could also put the IDs from R into an array and choose one randomly from that.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the getIdentifier.  Could you show me how it would be used?  I'm not sure what it would do to help me retrieve one array instead of all of them.  I will have 100's of arrays likely and will only want to retrieve one of them hopefully with getResources().getStringArray

Comment: getIdentifier takes three arguments: Name of the resource you're looking for (`ID` in this case), type of the resource (since it's R.array.ID, the type is "array") and the package name of your program (`context.getPackageName()`)... It returns an integer that is the same as R.array.ID and you can use that integer with getStringArray()

Comment: Sorry to be annoying but how do I then set my new array?

I currently have:

int j = getResources().getIdentifier( ID, "array", getPackageName());
 String[] NEWARRAY =  res.getStringArray(j);

Comment: Same way you'd normally do except you use the return value of getIdentifier in place of R.array.ID when calling getStringArray